# Mysqli Group Array Print Count of Group

Tags: php, mysqli, group-by

I'm querying my database to group all the similar records and count them.

Here is my current code:

```
$query= 'SELECT digit_1, count(digit_1) FROM data GROUP BY digit_1 ';

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["digit_1"], $row);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

This results:

```
0 (Array) 1 (Array) 2 (Array) 3 (Array) 4 (Array) 5 (Array) 6 (Array) 7 (Array) 8 (Array) 9 (Array)
```

How do I get the "count" to print instead of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did little modification in your code,have a look

```
$query= 'SELECT digit_1, count(digit_1) as count FROM data GROUP BY digit_1 ';
                                          ----^
                if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

                    /* fetch associative array */
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row['digit_1'], $row['count']);
                                                               ----^
                    }

                    /* free result set */
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
```